# Call getMethodID() got NoSuchMethodError from JNI in AOSP. Build apk from android studio have no problem

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, android-source

Building the APK from the Android Studio have no problem. Which is using Android.mk. I use ndk-build to build the TestLib.so

I want to move the code to AOSP. It builds successfully, but a runtime error occurs.

Error message:

```
AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method `"Lcom/example/TestTool;.nativeCompleteCallback([B)V"`
```

Android.bp:

```
cc_library_shared {
    name: "TestLib",
    srcs: [
        "jni/*.cc",
    ],
    arch: {
        arm: {
            instruction_set: "arm",
        },
    },
}
android_app {
    name: "Test_APP",

    srcs: [
        "src/**/*.java",
    ],
    product_specific: false,
    platform_apis: true,

    certificate: "platform",
    
    resource_dirs: ["src/main/res"],

    asset_dirs: ["src/main/assets"],

    required: ["TestLib"], 
    jni_libs: ["TestLib"],
    static_libs: [],
    
    optimize: {
        proguard_flags_files: ["proguard.cfg"],
    },
    
}
```

Java code:

```
public class TestTool {

    private final static String LOG_TAG = "TestTool";

    static {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "loadLibrary");
        System.loadLibrary("TestLib");
        nativeClassInit();
    }
    ...
    private void nativeCompleteCallback(byte[] testData) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "native Complete Callback");
        ...
    }
    ...
    private static native final boolean nativeClassInit();
}
```

JNI code:

```
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_com_example_TestTool_nativeClassInit(JNIEnv * env, jclass cls) {
    METHOD_nativeSynthCallback = env->GetMethodID(cls, "nativeCompleteCallback","([B)V");
    return JNI_TRUE;
}
```

I try to proguard.cfg. But it doesn't fix the problem.

```
-keepclassmembers class * extends com.example.TestTool { 
    private void nativeCompleteCallback(byte[]);
}
```

I have verified the /system/lib64/TestLib.so and /system/lib/TestLib.so have public symbols that correspond to the native method:

```
$ nm -D TestLib.so | grep "nativeClassInit"
```

Comment: Did you check with `nm` that your .so file has public symbols that correspond to the native method?

Comment: Yes. $ nm -D .so | grep "nativeClassInit"  I think java call JNI is no problem, but native code call getMethodID() is fail.

Comment: Please edit your question with the output. Also, are you checking the generated library or the contents of the APK?

Comment: I check /system/lib/.so and /system/lib64/.so How to check the contents of the APK?

Comment: You can just `unzip` it

Comment: No TestLib.so inside the APK. Is this a problem?

Comment: It would have to be `libTestLib.so`, and yes. If it is not present your code cannot load it.

Comment: Oh wait, you actually get an error from inside the native code.. :facepalm: I would double-check that the proguard keep rules are being applied then.

Comment: The App is a system App. Why the app cannot load from /system/lib64/?